# Can a regular directed graph be axiomatized in first order Logic?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, axioms

Given the first order edge relation $E$ is it possible to axiomatize directed graphs where every vertex has an equal amount of incoming and outgoind edges, including graphs with infinite edges?

Comment: "including graphs with infinite edges" is a bit vague. Do you mean to allow the situation that a vertex could have infinitely many incoming and outgoing edges? In that case, do you require that any two vertices have the same infinite cardinality of incoming and outgoing edges, or just that any two vertices have infinitely many? (Also, you should always write "infinitely many edges" rather than "infinite edges". The latter suggests that each edge is infinite - of course, that makes no sense in this context, but consider "infinitely many groups" vs "infinite groups").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any fixed $n$ the statement "the vertex $x$ has in-degree $n$", and the statement "the vertex $x$ has out-degree $n$" are both first order.

Indeed if $E(x,y)$ means there is an edge going from $x$ to $y$, and if $n>0$ then

$$ \varphi_n(x)=  \exists x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}\; \left( \bigwedge_{\substack{i,j < n \\ i \neq j}} x_i \neq x_j \land \bigwedge_{i < n}E(x_i, x) \land \left(\forall y\; E(y,x) \rightarrow \bigvee_{i<n} y=x_i \right)\right)$$

means $x$ has exactly $n$ different incoming edges (it has in-degree $n$), whereas

$$ \psi_n(x)=  \exists x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}\; \left( \bigwedge_{\substack{i,j < n \\ i \neq j}} x_i \neq x_j \land \bigwedge_{i < n}E(x,x_i) \land \left(\forall y\; E(x,y) \rightarrow \bigvee_{i<n} y=x_i \right)\right)$$

means $x$ it has exactly $n$ outcoming edges (it has out-degree $n$). If you like you can also write predicates $\varphi_0(x)$ and $\psi_0(x)$ stating there are no incoming or outcoming edges respectively to $x$.

**Edit**

If you want a theory whose models are the graphs in which for each vertex the in-degree mathces the out-degree, you just need to add a numerable axiom schema $\mathcal{A}=\{\forall x, \varphi_n(x) \leftrightarrow \psi_n(x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Instead to get a theory whose models are all the directed graphs such that:

*for all nodes $x,y$ the in-degree of $x$ and $y$ are equal, and the out degree of $x$ and $y$ are equal*

(which, as I understood from the comments, should be what you are looking for)
it suffices add to the axiom schemata $\mathcal{B}=\{\forall x \forall y \varphi_n(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi_n(y)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathcal{C}=\{\forall x \forall y \psi_n(x)\leftrightarrow \psi_n(y)\}_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$.

**Edit 2**

As for managing infinite in-degrees and out-degrees: the best you can do is an axiom schema in which you say that either all nodes have the same finite in-degree or all nodes have infinite in-degrees. And an analogue for out-degrees.

You can do it as follows: let $\varphi_{\ge n}(x)$ be the satement "x has in-degree $\ge n$", that is

$$ \varphi_{\ge n}(x)=  \exists x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}\; \left( \bigwedge_{\substack{i,j < n \\ i \neq j}} x_i \neq x_j \land \bigwedge_{i < n}E(x_i, x) \right)$$

then the axiom schema
$$\mathcal{D}=\{ \big(\forall x\forall y, \, \varphi_{\ge n}(x)\rightarrow \varphi_{\ge n+1}(y)\big) \lor \big( \forall x \forall y \varphi_{m}(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi_m(y) \big)\}_{n,m \in \mathbb{N}}$$

tells you that either all nodes have the same finite in degree or all nodes have  infinite in-degree: indeed if there is a node with finite degree $n$ then $\forall x\forall y, \, \varphi_{\ge n}(x)\rightarrow \varphi_{\ge n+1}(y)$ is false hence $\mathcal{D}$ is satisfied only if for every $m$ one has $\forall x \forall y \varphi_{m}(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi_m(y)$. If instead all nodes have infinite in-degree $\forall x\forall y, \, \varphi_{\ge n}(x)\rightarrow \varphi_{\ge n+1}(y)$ holds for all $n$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is satisfied.

You can add a similar axiom schema for the out-degrees.

You cannot however have a first order theory of regular directed graphs that can force nodes to have have all the same infinite cardinal as in-degrees (or out-degrees).

Indeed any dense linear order without extrema is a directed graph. For example $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ where you take $<$ as edge relation is a regular directed graph. Now note that $(\mathbb{Q} \cup [0,1], <)$, where $[0,1]$ is a real interval, still is a dense linear orded without extrema, but all $x>0$ have $2^{\aleph_0}$ in-degree, whereas all $x\le 0$ have $\aleph_0$ in-degree.

Since the theory of dense linear orders without extrema is complete you have that $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ and $(\mathbb{Q} \cup [0,1], <)$ are elementarily equivalent and hence every first order theory in the signature $\{<\}$ having $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ as a model has also $(\mathbb{Q} \cup [0,1], <)$ as a model.

Comment: I think "every vertex has an equal amount of incoming and outgoing edges" was intended to mean "every vertex has the same in degree and the same out degree".

Comment: Yes, $\varphi_n(x)$ means in-degree of $x$ is $n$ and $\psi_n(x)$ means out-degree of $x$ is $n$ so $\forall x, \varphi_n(x) \leftrightarrow \psi_n(x)$ means that every vertex having $n$ as in-degree has $n$ as out-degree, if you state it for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ you have the condition of in and out of degrees of each vertex being the same. If you state instead $\forall x \varphi_n(x) \land \psi_n(x)$ you have a $n$-regular directed graph.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that the OP meant "for all vertices $x$ and $y$, the in degree of $x$ equals the in degree of $y$, and the out degree of $x$ equals the out degree of $y$".

Comment: Oh i see. Fixed as an edit.

Comment: It seems your answer only helps with graphs where all vertices have finite degree, so I don't think this fully answers the OP's question.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I fixed it in a further edit: you can include the case of all vertices having  infinite in(or out)-degree, but you can't have a first order theory that has control over infinite cardinalities.